# Creating CSS and JQuery Tabs

Tags: jquery, html, css, tabs

i need like the tabs that google chrome has but then with CSS, HTML and JQuery (for anime) is there someone that can do this for me and also wants to post it here.

If so thanks in advance!!!

Comment: This is way too unspecific. You need to try to make it yourself and search for help with particular things you can't do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe that's what you're looking for?

https://jqueryui.com/tabs/